# Starting Ruby on Rails server on Windows automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, server

Im a totally newbie in Rails and i have a problem. Every single time Im rebooting my PC i have to run my server which is based on Ruby on Rails with console command in the right directory. There is my problem - I have to make something to run my server automatically with booting Windows.
@BTW: Is there any possibility to hide a console?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Let me know if the answer below solves your problem

Comment: @K.Gol I am glad it works for you, please accept the answer so it can help other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a batch file with the instruction what you give in the command prompt like

```
cd projects\myapp
ruby script\server
```

and then drop a copy of the file to Windows Start -> All Programs -> start up folder.

Comment: I'll try this! Thx for response!